# laravel call to undefined relationship that exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
 Call to undefined relationship [App\Models\Challenge] on model [App\Models\UserChallenge]
```

Even though I have the relationship defined:

UserChallenge:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Eloquent\UserChallenge as EloquentUserChallenge;

class UserChallenge extends EloquentUserChallenge {
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function challenge()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Challenge');
    }

};
```

Challenge:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Eloquent\Challenge as EloquentChallenge;

class Challenge extends EloquentChallenge {

};
```

Comment: You haven't determined a foreignKey

Comment: Wait.. The ->belongsTo should be in the Model file, whats with the Models DIR?

Comment: Have you did somewhere `UserChallenge::with(App\Models\Challenge')...` ?!

Answer (score 3):

This also can happen when you call the relationship with `->withTrashed()` at the end like this:

```
// User model for example

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment')->withTrashed(); // <===
}
```

But you forget to use `SoftDelete` in the `Comment` model.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the `->with()` method requires me to reference the method that returns the relationship rather than the referenced model:

So when I change the query that caused the problems from:

```
$this->userChallenges()->with(Challenge::class)->latest()->limit($limit)->get();
```

to

```
$this->userChallenges()->with('challenge')->latest()->limit($limit)->get();
```

it works.

Comment: That's what i am asking for in the comment i guessed it's the case :)

Answer (score 0):

The `UserChallenge` model must have a reference to the `Challenge`, usually it's `challenge_id`. Then you can use it like this

```
$userChallenge->challenge
```